# Shortest Distance from Leaf to Root of a Directed tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, shortest-path

Here is a very interesting problem which I have encountered: there is a directed tree in which the weight of each node changes with time and I have to find the distance from the root to some node.

**Problem Statement:**

- There’s a long queue in front of a ticket counter. Here are the queue
  considerations.
- There can be max 2 incoming queues merging at a junction point
- There can be only one outgoing queue from any junction point
- There can be multiple junction points & the queues move
  uni-directionally
- There will be only one final ticket counter point to which all the
  queues lead
- There are multiple entry points for the fans to reach the
  counter
- I need to design a system that can suggest to the fans the
  “Optimal Path” and its “Expected Time" to reach the counter

The expected time to reach the counter from a queue depends on the number of people in that queue plus the number of people in the other queues.

- Time taken to cross the ticket counter and receive the ticket is 1
  time unit
- Assume that there is a policeman standing at each junction point
  whose job is to open the junction gate to send people from the
  in-queue(s) to the out-queue . If there are multiple in-queues for a
  junction, the policeman will send fans from each queue one by one
  alternatively

For example, if there are 2 in-queues containing 3 fans each, the leading person from queue1 will be sent in first, followed by the leading person from queue2, followed by next person from queue1 and so on. It’s an alternate pick between the incoming queues.

[Full Problem Statement](https://www.hackerearth.com/walmartlabs-java-developer-hiring-challenge/algorithm/ticket-counter-8/description/)

For a Given Input

- The first line contains the number of junctions
- The second line contains the number of queues
- The next 'e' lines contain three values: the start junction, the end
  junction and the number of people on this queue. (This is also the maximum number of people that can stand in this queue.)

Calculate the **minimum time** for a person to reach the ticket counter who is just about to enter any queue. Also, output the **path** that he should take to reach the counter in minimum time in the worst case (at each junction point, the policeman starts choosing people from the in-queue other than the one we are calculating the minimum time for).

**How can one solve this type of time-varying problem?**

For Example:

```
7
6
1 5 9
2 5 5 
3 6 1
4 6 3 
5 7 7 
6 7 4
```

Graph Looks Like This: 
[image]

### Ticket counter point: 7

### Entry points: 1, 2, 3, 4

- Time required for a person who is just entering the queue from entry
  point 3: 1 person from queue(3,6) + 2 people from queue(4,6) + 4
  people from queue(6,7) + 7 people from queue(5,7) + 1 person from
  queue(1,5) will go before this person.

### Optimal time = 15

### Path is 3 -> 6 -> 7

Comment: Clicking on the link asks me to log in to HackerEarth.  Can you give some evidence that this is not part of a *current* programming contest that a person can verify without having to make an account there?  (E.g. screenshot)

Comment: @j_random_hacker I have an account and just checked it. It says

"The challenge is over and this problem has been moved to practice area. You can either submit your solution here or
Go to Practice Area. Also further submissions won't affect the leaderboard. "

Comment: Just thinking. Is there any reason why simply getting the shortest path won't work here?

Comment: Thanks for that @mk.

Comment: Any idea how to solve this @j_random_hacker ?

Comment: (1) In your example, why do you say that 2 people from queue (4, 6) will leave before the new arrival at queue (3, 6)?  If the first person let through at a junction comes from the left queue, then only 1 person from queue (4, 6) will precede the new arrival.  (2) It's important to know whether the first person let through a junction always comes from the left (or always comes from the right) queue, but you don't say.  (3) By "expected time", do you actually mean "average time over all possible starting queues"?  (This is the standard meaning of "expected".)  Or do you mean "minimum time"?

Comment: this seems to me like all-to-one shortest path problem, where the leafs are the set of starting nodes and the root is the goal node. What do you think?

Comment: @FrankS101 yes, see my answer below.

Comment: Funny, I would imagine opposite to be a better organization. One entrance (queue) and several exits (ticket counters).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem can be solved by finding the **shortest path** from each entry node (leaves) to the exit node (root).

In my implementation below I used an adjacency matrix to represent that kind of (directed) graph, but you can think of it as a binary tree (because the problem defined maximum 2 input queues for each junction).

### Pseudo-code

```
int shortestPath(root)
    if (both childs exists)
        return min(shortestPath(node->left),shortestPath(node->right))*2+1
    if (left child exists)
        return shortestPath(node->left)
    if (right child exists)
        return shortestPath(node->right)
    return 0; //no childs
```

The only difference between a *normal* shortest path and this problem is that whenever we have **two** incoming queues, the policeman sends fans from each queue one by one alternatively. Which means that in order to pass that queue it will take **double the time +1**. The +1 is because we assume that he starts from the longer queue path.

### C++ Code

Here is a working C++ code that returns a pair with both the optimal time and its path. In case there are more than one optimal paths it will return only one of them.

```
const pair<int,vector<int>>& min(const pair<int,vector<int>>& a, const pair<int,vector<int>>& b) {
  return (a.first < b.first) ? a : b;
}

pair<int,vector<int>> findShortestPath(vector<vector<int>>& graph, int v){
    vector<pair<int,vector<int>>> childs;
    for (int i=0; i<v; i++){
        if (graph[i][v] != -1){
            pair<int,vector<int>> path = findShortestPath(graph,i);
            path.second.push_back(v+1);
            childs.push_back(make_pair(path.first + graph[i][v], path.second));
        }
    }
    if (childs.size() == 2){
        pair<int,vector<int>> path = min(childs[0],childs[1]);
        return make_pair(path.first*2+1, path.second);
    }
    if (childs.size() == 1){
        return make_pair(childs[0].first,childs[0].second);
    }
    else{
        vector<int> start = {v+1};
        return make_pair(0,start);
    }
}
```

The **time complexity** of this code is `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of vertices. You might also be able to implement it in `O(n)` using adjacency list representation (= binary tree).

---

For completeness, here is also the `main` for creating the graph from the given input and printing the optimal time and path. [See this live test of your example's input](http://ideone.com/jAwH9k)

```
int main()
{
    int n, e;
    cin >> n; //num of vertices
    cin >> e; //num of queues
    vector<vector<int>> graph;

    //initialize graph matrix cells to -1
    graph.resize(n);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        graph[i].resize(n);
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
            graph[i][j] = -1;
    }

    //add edges and their weights
    for (int i=0;i<e;i++){
        int s,d,val;
        cin >> s >> d >> val;
        graph[s-1][d-1] = val;
    }

    //run algorithm
    pair<int,vector<int>> path = findShortestPath(graph, n-1);

    //print results
    cout << path.first << endl;
    for (int i=0;i<path.second.size()-1;i++)
        cout << path.second[i] << " -> ";
    cout << path.second[path.second.size()-1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems you solution is correct. Can you please explain the gist behind this why simple shortest path algo is working correctly , as the people in each edge are changing with time.

Comment: If for example you are standing in one queue that enters to some node `x` and there is another queue that enters that same node. How much time will it take you to pass that node? It will take double the length of your queue because we alternate between those queues. How can I be sure that there are enough persons in the other queue to alternate? Because from the last recursive call we chose to stand in the minimum path, meaning that the other path must have more persons in it. When there is only one queue that enters the node then the time to pass it is simply the length of the queue.

Answer (score -2):

This should be solved by dynamic programming.
Let P(j) be the position of the person ,if it takes the optimal fan , to pass through the junction point j. For example P(6) = 4 in your case , because someone arriving at junction point 3 will be the 4th to pass through junction point 6 (after P27,P26 and P28).
The following three propositions are obvious and solve the problem.
If a "junction point" j is a fan , P(j) = 1 (base case)
If a "junction point" j is a proper junction point with children l and r , and there are x people in the queue between l and j and y people in the queue between r and j , we have P(j) = 2 * min( P(l) + x , P(r) + y)
If someone if the n'th to go through the counter, it takes n-1 time to get there.
You can get the time easily using DP and with some book keeping(if the min is achieved n the left or on the right) you can get which is the optimal fan.